# Is $3^n>2^n n^3$ as n approaches infinity? Or is the opposite true?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

My teachers are having a debate regarding this inequality. One of them used a limit to try to prove that $3^n>2^n n^3$ is in fact true,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3^n}{2^n n^3} &= \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{3}{2})^n \space\frac{1}{n^3} \\
  &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1.5^n}{n^3}\\
  &= \infty \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: The fact is true but the first line of the proof makes no sense, as there is no $x$ in the expression. Replace $x$ with $n$ and you are fine, except the proof seems to rely on knowing that limit is $\infty$, which is essentially the same as knowing that the inequality you are trying to prove is true for large $n$.  So the proof is not convincing unless you can find a way to prove that limit.

Comment: @Michael Oh yeah you're right, whoops.

Comment: It is not a proof at all as there is no explanation of the (crucial) last $=$.

Comment: The proof must also be handled _carefully_ because the inequality is only true for $ \ n = 1 \ $ and $ \ n \ge 24 \ $ (!!) , if you are restricting this to integers .

Comment: Consider $a_n=(3/2)^n$ and $b_n=n^3$. We have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3}{2}$ while $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3$, which is less than $3/2$ for any $n\geq 7$. Since $a_{24} > b_{24}$ we have $a_n > b_n$ for any $n\geq 24$.

Comment: The last equality can be proved by using De l'hopital

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **as n approaches $\infty$**, this equation holds true:

If $3^n > 2^nn^3$ were to false, $3^n < 2^nn^3$ would be true. Simplifying this gives:

$$(\frac{3}{2})^n < n^3$$
$$(\frac{3}{2})^{\frac{n}{3}} < n$$
$$(\frac{3}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}} < n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

At the previous step, there is an identity when taking the limit of n to $\infty$: $\lim{_{n \to \infty}}, n^\frac{1}{n} \to 1$
$$(\frac{3}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}} < 1$$
This is clearly wrong and therefore, if we reversed the inequality, it would be true, proving that $$\lim{_{n \to \infty}}: 3^n > 2^nn^3$$.

**Note**: This only works if n approaches $\infty$ (for large n values only). I  keyed this function in binary search program and found that it if the values for n were **restricted to $\mathbb N$**, the lowest value would be 24, for this equation to hold true.

$\therefore n >= 24$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combinatorial proof of the inequality.

Let us look at functions from the set $A=\lbrace 1,2,3,\cdots,n\rbrace$ to the set $B=\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$. There are $3^n$ such functions.
Now, we can separate these functions into parts $F_k$ where $F_k=\lbrace f: |f^{-1}(2)|=k \rbrace$ and $B^A= \cup^{n}_{k=0} F_k$ (disjoint union). Let us try to calculate $|F_k|$. We can choose the set of elements in $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=2$ in $^nC_k$ ways. The rest of the elements can be assigned values in $2^{n-k}$ ways. So, $|F_k|=2^{n-k}\times ^nC_k$.

Now, make the following observation. $|F_k|>|F_{k-1}|$ for large enough $n$. Why? Because $^nC_k$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$ and therefore, will outgrow the polynomial $^nC_{k-1}$ of degree $k-1$. This can also be shown combinatorially but this is just easier.

$3^n=|B^A|> \Sigma_{k=3}^{28} |F_k|> 24|F_3|+|F_3|= 24\times2^{n-3}\times \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}+|F_3|= 2^n(n^3 -3n^2+3n)+ |F_3|> 2^nn^3$ for large enough $n$. This was to be shown.

Comment: I only posted this because you were looking for an alternate proof. Cheers!